# GIT push to multiple repositories hosted by one gerrit server

Tags: git, git-push, gerrit

I tried but failed to find an answer to this from old posts. So I am sorry if it already exists and I reposted the question.

We have a problem where we have one gerrit server hosting multiple git repositories. Some times same commit needs to be pushed to two or more repositories but not always. Now we have an issue where gerrit complains about the change id already used in other commit, when we try to do the push to the second repo.

Is there a easy way to push the same change in to multiple repositories with different change id?

Or how to create a new change id?

Br,
Jarno S.

Comment: by change id, you mean the commit id, i.e. the commit SHA-1 hash? You paid attention you specified different remotes?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to replicate, you can use gerrit replication. But that happens across the board.

Now - If you want to push a selective changeSet (that to automatically) You can accomplish changeset-merged hook. But what is guarantee that there is no merge conflict.

How would you automatically detect if this commit is good to push or not, is it based on comment ?

Your best option is create git patches and apply it to next repository